# Geo IP filter not creating geo point type Elastic Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm working on a logstash pipeline. I am using the geoip filter. When viewing the logs, I can see the location.lat and the location.lon, as both floats, but I don't see a type that is a geoPoint

My pipeline filter

```
    geoip {
       id => "f5_bigip_ltm_src_geo"
       source => "[clientip]"
       #fields => [ "city_name", "continent_code", "country_name", "latitude", "longitude", "location", "postal_code", "region_name", "isp", "timezone" ]
       cache_size => "4096"
       #tag_on_failure => ["_geoip_failure_ltm"]
    }
```

Generated fields:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash does not have support for a [geo_point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) data type. You have to use a [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) in Elasticsearch. When ECS compatibility is disabled (which used to be the default) the default target for the geoip filter is [geoip], and the default template for an elasticsearch output set the mapping for that field to be geo_point. logstash would send the geoip field to elasticsearch as a JSON object `{ "geoip": { "location": { "lat": 41.12,  "lon": -71.34 } }`. That is one of several formats that elasticsearch will convert to a geo_point provided that there is a mapping telling it to do so.

When ECS compatability is enabled the target varies, but you still need a mapping in elasticsearch.